# Update a Firestore database ID?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to update a Firestore database ID? E.g. I have a database with ID `test-123`, is it possible to update this ID to `default`?

I've gone through the guides [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-databases?&_ga=2.49228773.-2146502246.1692180071#update_database_configuration) but do not see any commands for updating the database ID after creation.

I am NOT referring to a document ID in the database, I am referring to the database itself.

Comment: There is no way to rename a document.  You'd have to copy the document into a new one, then delete the original.

Comment: I'm not referring to a document in the database, I'm referring to the database itself. The database has an ID, it is either the (default) database or it is a named ID.

Answer (score 1):

As @DougStevenson already mentioned in his comment, there is no way you can rename a document ID.

If you're not referring to the document ID and you're referring to the database ID, then please note that if you're using the Firebase Console, there is no database ID visible, but just the application ID:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/app-id/firestore/data/
//
```

On the other hand, if you're using the Google Cloud Console, the URL of a Firestore database looks like this:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/databases/-default-/data/panel/books?project=app-id
//
```

Which contains the `default` ID of the database. When you create a new project and you activate Firestore, this is the ID that is assigned by default. On the other hand, if you create a new Firestore instance, then you can assign any ID you want.

Let's say, you have two databases, a `default` one and a `test-123` one. If you finished testing and you want your `test-123` database to become `default`, basically you want to rename the `test-123` back to `default`, please note that this is not possible. And it makes sense because the `default` already exists and you can simply overwrite a Firestore instance on top of the other. If you need to transfer all the data from a Firestore instance to another instance you have to do that yourself. Once you finish that operation, you can simply delete the `test-123` database so you can have only one instance, the `default` one.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?